# jQuery / jCarousel: Issue with last slide image when wrapping content

Tags: jquery, slideshow, wrapper, jcarousel, word-wrap

I’m using the jQuery jCarousel on a blog of mine and have ran into a problem which is related to using the auto slideshow function and to wrap the content at the end, so it restarts from picture one.

When the slider comes to the last image it stands there for the amount of seconds I’ve instructed it to and then moves the image 20 pixels to the left because restart with image one. I’ve tried almost everything to find the error but just can’t seem to get my head around it.

I’ve made a preview of the slideshow and the error here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70953/slideshow.htm

You will see the error after the first image has changed and the second image changes (about 5 seconds after the site has loaded).

I’m using jQuery version 1.7.2.

My jCarousel options looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider-holder").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 3,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: _init_slider,
        itemFirstInCallback: _set_slide,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });

    $('.field').each(function() {
        check_fields(this);
    });

    $('.field').focus(function() {
        if(this.title==this.value) {
            this.value = '';
            check_fields(this);
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(this.value=='') {
            this.value = this.title;
            check_fields(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks
- Mestika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember a problem like this.  It has something to do with width on your css.

In your slider.css change 940 to 920.

```
#slider-holder .jcarousel-clip {
    height: 420px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried to change the width as you said but same thing still happens.

Comment: Keep messing with some of the other widths in the CSS file.

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the problem. It was the #slider-holder .jcarousel-clip class that needed a finetuning but instead of decrease the width, I had to increase it with 20px so the width was 960px.. Thanks for your answer, you sent me off in the right direction!

Comment: Great to hear!  I knew it had something to do with CSS.  The logic chekcs the widths and somehow tries to calculate the amount of items based on that, I think. Thanks for coming back and updating us on the fix.